# How do we distinguish between the use of the overloaded [] operator for getting and setting?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am writing an assignment that requires me to implement my own (basic) vector class. One unusual requirement, is that we must provide a function which gives the sum of all elements in the vector. This function should cache the sum, so subsequent calls can be answered in constant time if the vector has not changed.

The problem I am having is trying to figure out *when* it has changed.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyVector {
    int* v;
    int size;
    int totalSum;
    bool upToDate;
public:
    MyVector(int size) : size{size}, totalSum{0}, upToDate{false} {
        v = new int[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            v[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    // Set - should only be called as an lvalue
    int& operator[](unsigned int i) {
        upToDate = false;
        std::cerr << "Set\n";
        return v[i];
    }

    // Get - should only be called as an rvalue
    int operator[](unsigned int i) const {
        std::cerr << "Get\n";
        return v[i];
    }

    // Get sum of array -- result is cached for performance
    int sum() {
        if(!upToDate) {
            upToDate = true;
            totalSum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                totalSum += v[i];
            }
        }
        return totalSum;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyVector mv(3);
    mv[0] = 1;
    mv[1] = 2;
    mv[2] = 3;
    std::cout << "Sum " << mv.sum() << "\n";

    int first = mv[0];
    std::cout << "First element is " << first << "\n";

    std::cout << "Sum " << mv.sum() << "\n";
}
```

I've provided two overloaded versions of the [] operator -- one for getting and one for setting. Whenever the setting version of the operator is invoked, I assume that the vector is being changed.

```
# Output
Set
Set
Set
Sum 6
Set
First element is 1
Sum 6
```

However, it seems the setting version of the operator is *always* being called, even when it is being used as an rvalue.

How do I overload the [] operator correctly to distinguish between its use for getting and setting?

Comment: The approach to solving this problem is flawed as the reference returned from the non-const version of `operator[]` may be saved by the caller and later used to alter the values in the array bypassing all attempts to detect the change. The only way I can think of attempting to solve the problem, as posed, would be by returning proxy object, however this is possibly out of scope of the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a reference to the stored int directly, you can return a thin proxy wrapper around that reference, which can watch for changes. In the majority of cases, the compiler should inline it and optimize it away (you can try to benchmark it and compare).

The wrapper class:

```
class Item {
    int &value;
    MyVector &myVector;

public:
    Item(int &value, MyVector &myVector) : value(value), myVector(myVector) {}

    Item& operator=(int newvalue) {
        std::cerr << "Set\n";
        value = newvalue;
        myVector.upToDate = false;
        return *this;
    }

    // TODO: Reimplement also operators like +=, -=, etc
    // You can use boost helpers for that.

    operator int() const {
        std::cerr << "Get\n";
        return value;
    }
};
```

Changes to MyVector:

```
class MyVector {
    // ...

    Item operator[](unsigned int i) {
        return Item(v[i], *this);
    }

    const int operator[](unsigned int i) const {
        std::cerr << "Const Get\n";
        return v[i];
    }

// ...
}
```

It can be used exactly the same way:

```
int main() {
    MyVector mv(3);
    mv[0] = 1;
    mv[1] = 2;
    mv[2] = 3;
    std::cout << "Sum " << mv.sum() << "\n";

    int first = mv[0];
    std::cout << "First element is " << first << "\n";

    std::cout << "Sum " << mv.sum() << "\n";
}
```